# Integrating Hive with PowerBI

Tags: windows, hive, odbc, powerbi, hortonworks-data-platform

I am on windows 7 machine, trying to integrate Hive and PowerBI.
My Hive uses derby as metastore and it is running locally.

Now I am trying to connect my local running hive database to Microsoft powerBI and I am using Horton works Hive ODBC Driver DSN setup for it.

I am unable to figure out the correct Host and Port combinations to configure the Hive ODBC Driver DSN setup and I always get the following error:

```
[Hortonworks][DriverSupport] (1110) Unexpected response received from server. Please ensure the server host and port specified for the connection are correct and confirm if SSL should be enabled for the connection.
```

My question is what should be the `Host` and `Port` name?

Since Hive has a default port of `10000`. I have it here and I am trying the host names with my ip (`192.168.5.1`), `0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1` but nothing worked so far.

Can I connect my local hive to PowerBI?

[This is my ODBC DRIVER DSN SETUP configuration as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfXCP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to follow the below article step and you will able to connect to the hive server.

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/61185/visualizing-hive-data-using-microsoft-power-bi.html

Please check the localhost:10000 & try to query using command prompt and then check again.

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/starting-hive/content/hive_start_a_command_line_query_locally.html